# Got error in whatsapp while sharing video in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentprovider

[Showing error like this when sharing videos in whatsapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWwOj.jpg)

'The following is my code to share document,image and videos.The image and document are sharing with no issues ,the issue only occurs while sharing video in to whatsapp.'

```
  shareFileUri=uriFromFile(context,File(path))
                    val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                    shareIntent.type = "*/*"
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  shareFileUri)
                    shareIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                  // shareIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                    shareIntent.flags=Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
                    // shareIntent.type = "application/*"
                    // context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "share.."))
                    val chooser = createChooser(shareIntent, "Share File")

                    val resInfoList: List<ResolveInfo> = context.packageManager
                        .queryIntentActivities(chooser, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)

                    for (resolveInfo in resInfoList) {
                        val packageName: String = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName
                        context.grantUriPermission(
                            packageName,
                            shareFileUri,
                            FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                        )
                    }

                    context.startActivity(chooser)
```

'get uri path'

```
fun uriFromFile(context:Context, file:File):Uri {

    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        FileProvider.getUriForFile(context.applicationContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)
    } else {
        Uri.fromFile(file)
    }
}
```

'This is my file provider in manifest '

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
            tools:replace="android:resource" />
    </provider>
```

'The following is the xml path for file provider'

```
<paths>

<files-path
    name="internal_files"
    path="."/>
<external-files-path
    name="external_files_path"
    path="."/>
```